# Print RAW data to network shared printer fails from IIS server, but works properly in development env

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, networking, printing

I'm developing an ASP.NET application that requires printing. I need to send RAW data from server to a dot matrix printer which is connected to a client computer in the network.

Printing works properly in development env (VS2008). When publishing it to an intranet IIS server (Windows 8.1 OS), printing fails even not reaching the print queue. I tried the following..

1. click "Add Printer"
2. "Add a Local Printer"
3. "Create a New Port"
4. use the "Local Port" option
5. at "Enter a Port Name" enter: "\Computername\Printername"

Now, my data reach the printer queue with "Error - Printing" Status.. Any help?

[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kErAP.png)

Comment: Check user permissions, IIS will run under it's own user, so probably that user will not have access to the spooler

Comment: thanx ur prompt reply..  ya, I try that one too. change the permissions of user to Everyone. The applicationpooling identity is set as "Network Service".  but still have a problem..